# CAAnimation path only within bounds of view/layer

Tags: swift, animation, uikit, core-animation

I have a UIView that is half of the screen. On tap on that view, I create a CAShapeLayer and then animate its path, like so:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "path")
    animation.toValue = endShape
    animation.duration = 0.7
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear) // animation curve is Ease Out
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = true
```

But the problem is that the shape layer expands beyond the bounds of the view.
Is it possible to keep it within the bounds?

Also tried varying masksToBounds property, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer
Basically I had a wrong view/layer hierarchy.
masksToBounds property should have been set on the superlayer, but I had it on the animated layer itself

Comment: If you accept this answer (your own) then others will know that this question will know that it's been answered.